# Intersection of two spheres (maximization ) in R

Tags: r, optimization, geometry, nonlinear-optimization

I want to find intersection of two spheres in R(which is a circle) and find max and min of coordinates on that circle.
The spheres are :

> S1: x^2+y^2+z^2=16
>
> S2: (x+1)^2+(y+1)^2+(z+1)^2=27

```
library(rgl)
s1 =spheres3d(x = 0, y = 0, z = 0, radius = 4)
s2 =spheres3d(x = -1, y = -1, z = -1, radius = sqrt(27))
```

I think the plane which the circle is on that will be: ( is there any way that R can find this from S1&S2?).

P1: x+y+z=4

So now I have a maximization problem (P1 subject to S1 and S2): So I did this code:

```
eval_f <- function( x ) {
  return( list( "objective" = (x[1]+x[2]+x[3])-4,
                "gradient" = c(1,1,1) ))}
# constraint functions
eval_g_eq <- function( x ) {
  constr <- cbind(c( (x[1]+1)^2 + (x[2]+1)^2 + (x[3]+1)^2  - 27) , c(x[1]^2+x[2]^2+x[3]^2-16))
  grad <- cbind ( c( 2.0*(x[1]+1),
             2.0*(x[2]+1),
             2.0*(x[3]+1)
             ),c(2*x[1],2*x[2],2*x[3]) )
  return( list( "constraints"=constr, "jacobian"=grad ) )
}


# initial values
x0 <- c( 0, 0, 0 )

local_opts <- list( "algorithm" = "NLOPT_LD_MMA",
                    "xtol_rel" = 1.0e-7 )
opts <- list( "algorithm" = "NLOPT_LD_AUGLAG",
              "xtol_rel" = 1.0e-7,
              "maxeval" = 1000,
              "local_opts" = local_opts )
res <- nloptr( x0=x0, 
               eval_f=eval_f,eval_g_eq=eval_g_eq,
               opts=opts)
print( res )
```

Link to the manual - [nloptr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/nloptr/nloptr.pdf) function.

But I think there is a mistake!

Comment: I don't see how this is a maximization problem. If anything it might be a minimization problem, but you need a non-linear function to minimize (your objective function seems to be linear). Also not sure what you are looking for. A plane? But I see no plane parameters.

Comment: And sphere-sphere intersection can be solved in closed form, no need for numerical optimzation here: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Sphere-SphereIntersection.html

Comment: @MikeWise : P1 is a plane , right? and the plane intersection with sphere is circle! Now I want to find maximum of one coordinate (say z) in that circle.

Comment: So it is a constrained optimization problem, with your points being constrained to lie in some implicitly defined manifold? If it even is a manifold (it is in this case though). I think that is not an easy thing to program in general.

Comment: well, its constrained optimization and I have provided related codes. But I'm not mathematician, so dont understand your talks about manifold.